# Why does Lingvo not use `tf.data`

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

[Lingvo](https://github.com/tensorflow/lingvo) does not seem to use `tf.data`.
Why is that?

It might be just for historical reasons, because Lingvo is older than `tf.data`. But maybe I'm also missing something?